# How to select json value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

**json**

```
 var employees ='{"skills":[{"category":"JavaScript","tests":[{"name":"One","score":90}, {"name":"Two","score":96}]},{"category":"CouchDB","tests":[{"name":"One","score":79},"name":"Two","score":84}]}]}';
```

**jquery**

```
 var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(employees);
 for(i=0; i<obj.skills[0].tests[0].length; i++)
 {
  alert(obj.skills.tests.name[i]);
  }
```

Hi Here i need is in alert i want output is
"one 90
two 96"
i want first test values to alert or print in ul li. any one help me.

Comment: `alert(obj.skills[0].tests[0].name[i]);` missed `[0]`

Comment: @Satpal no its not working

Comment: First is your JSON is not valid. You require to update it with `{"skills":[{"category":"JavaScript","tests":[{"name":"One","score":90}, {"name":"Two","score":96}]},{"category":"CouchDB","tests":[{"name":"One","score":79},{"name":"Two","score":84}]}]}`

Comment: guys json is big and its working gud checked in http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ i have doubt in forloop and alert please correct it... i checked with ur code but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test object is not a list but has 2 properties `name` and `score`:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(employees);
var test0 = obj.skills[0].tests[0];
alert(test0.name+' '+test0.score);
```

To show for all tests of a skill:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(employees);
var testi;
for(var i=0;i<obj.skills[0].tests.length;i++){
    testi = obj.skills[0].tests[i];
    alert(testi.name+' '+testi.score);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you use _.forEach in lodash just to make it easy, however if you want to use native javascript find below.
ALso please note you have missed a opening braces i.e. "{" before

> {  //this is not there
>   "name":"Two",
>   "score":84
>   }

Solution

```
 var obj = JSON.parse(employees);    
 for(i=0; i<obj.skills.length; i++)
 {
    var temp = obj.skills[i];
    for(j=0;j<temp.tests.lengh;j++)
    {
        var outputObj = temp.tests[j];
        alert(outputObj.name+" "+outputObj.score);
    }

 }
```

If you dont want output of all skills then remove outer forloop i.e.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(employees);        

for(j=0;j<obj.skills[0].tests.lengh;j++)
{
    var outputObj = temp.tests[j];
    alert(outputObj.name+" "+outputObj.score);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use .`each` in jquery

```
 var employees = {
    "skills": [{
        "category": "JavaScript",
            "tests": [{
            "name": "One",
                "score": 90
        }, {
            "name": "Two",
                "score": 96
        }]

    }]
};

$.each(employees.skills, function (key, val) {

    for (var i in val.tests) {

        alert(val.tests[i].name);
        alert(val.tests[0].score);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

As from comment above by Satpal you missed the [0] in the loop, so that you cant able to alert data. So use like below

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(employees);
var test;
for(var i=0;i<obj.skills[0].tests.length;i++){
test = obj.skills[0].tests[i];
alert(test.name+' '+test.score);

}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Updated Satpal pls review

Comment: Why down vote? Can you explain i'll correct

Comment: OP Posted invalid JSON. But i didn't downvote you

Comment: Not me the downvote but `test.name` is a string, name[0] will return the first char. `i` is compared to `tests[0].length` but used on `tests[0].name`. Your code will return unexpected results.

Comment: @Sudharsan OP saying json is valid